# Cheap epoxy for Liquid Nitrogen temperatures?

Tags: cryogenics, epoxy

I have been testing acrylic in and out of a N<sub>2</sub> bath. It is a very thick piece so it is holding up surprisingly well.
I need to bond pieces of acrylic together for my application that will be submerged in N<sub>2</sub>.

In your experience have you used or know of any epoxy's that are cheaper that work at 77 K (-420 °F)?

I found this [epoxy] https://www.lakeshore.com/products/categories/overview/temperature-products/cryogenic-accessories/epoxy
but it seems a little expensive.

Comment: I would expect MMAs to work better at low temps than epoxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some valid alternatives after asking around...
[tedpella Silver epoxy ....](https://www.tedpella.com/SEMmisc_html/SEMpaint.aspx)

[Araldite for structure ....](https://www.perigeedirect.com/products/huntsman-araldite-2022-1-toughened-10-15-min-acrylate-mma-multi-use-formula?variant=32626245566567&currency=USD&utm_medium=product_sync&utm_source=google&utm_content=sag_organic&utm_campaign=sag_organic&utm_campaign=gs-2019-03-03&utm_source=google&utm_medium=smart_campaign&gclid=Cj0KCQjwhsmaBhCvARIsAIbEbH5-CIw4S1nxGUbXLza4vaE3UcIllxjK6aNEr7eXy5w9xJ8MZk-W3bYaAsuYEALw_wcB)

Superglue as long as it doesn't get wet.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use acrylic cement? It solvent welds the pieces together and leaves no "glue" behind, so it should work at the same temperatures the acrylic does.